# Subtracting two images of different sizes in Python using opencv

Tags: python-2.7, opencv3.0

How can I subtract two images of different sizes in Python using the opencv library?

For example, if I have:

`image1 (324x324)`
`image2 (222x101)`

Is it possible to get:

`image3 = image1 - image2`

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: And what result do you expect from that?

Comment: image of size max(image1.size,image2.size)@Miki